# Rewrite url of manufacturer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, manufacturer

I want to prettify every manufacturer url from default structure:

> mysite.com/store.html?manufacturer=107

To:

> mysite.com/nameofmanufacturer.html

I'm trying to do this by **"Catalog" > "URL Rewrite Management"**

[image]

But, It doesn't work (I get 404 error)

Is the right way?

Comment: It looks to me like you'd have to write a custom module with a controller that finds the manufacturer by name rather than id, then use some simple `.htaccess` rerwrites -> rewrite info: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners [check the part about `parrots/norwegian-blue/` from `get_product_by_name.php?product_name=norwegian-blue`

Comment: @mariobros , had you tried my solution below?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve ".html" after each url by below instruction:

> Go to System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine
>   Optimizations and modifying Product URL Suffix and Category URL Suffix
>   respectively.

But for your above request for change url from "mysite.com/store.html?manufacturer=107" to "mysite.com/nameofmanufacturer.html" , It seems you are trying to open category and filter manufacturer attribute. But its not possible.

You can do 1 thing which is better as per my suggestion:
Create category with "**nameofmanufacturer**" then you will get category url "**nameofmanufacturer.html**". NO need to include this category in MENU if you want. Also after this you can use "REWRITE URL" for redirect from "**mysite.com/store.html?manufacturer=107**" to "**mysite.com/nameofmanufacturer.html**". Hope this will help you. :)